# How to program date range based on current date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I've a requirement to pull order data pertaining to the latest invoice generated on semi-monthly basis. 
i.e. to give examples,

> **Case 1:** if today is Oct 30 and the latest invoice generated is as on
>   Oct 15, I'd like to see all order data between Oct 1 - Oct 15 (till
>   the invoice date)
>
> **Case 2:** if today is Mar 10 and the latest invoice is as on Feb 28, I'd
>   like to see all the order data between Feb 14 
>   and Feb 28

How to achieve this in SQL server? given I've order date and invoice date as two datetime columns in the table

Comment: most semi-monthly operations (that I am aware of) are on the 15th and the last day of the month. Do you have other special rules like your Feb 14 example?

Comment: If you have `invoice date` as a column in the table, why not just query based on `invoice date`? Showing a table schema, example data, and expected results would go a long way towards getting a clear and concise answer. [How to post a tsql question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) and [How-to-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I think you basically want:

```
select (case when day(getdate()) > 15
             then datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 15)
             else dateadd(day, -1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
        end) as last_invoice_date
```

Comment: well, my invoice date is not fixed on 15th and 30th always. 
E.g. (i) invoice will not happen on Jan 1 (being holiday), so it happens on Jan 2nd
(ii) Invoice does not happen on Feb 15 if it's not a leap year. If it's a leap year, it may happen on 15th. 
This is what is tricky.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for, it just selects all the data from an invoice table where the invoice date is between the latest invoice date and the latest invoice date minus 14 days (inclusive). You can change the 14 days to any number of days you like.

```
SELECT * FROM INVOICETABLE WHERE INVOICEDATE BETWEEN
(
SELECT TOP 1 DATEADD(DD,-14,INVOICEDATE) FROM INVOICETABLE ORDER BY INVOICEDATE DESC
)
AND
(
SELECT TOP 1 INVOICEDATE FROM INVOICETABLE ORDER BY INVOICEDATE DESC
)
```